# Swipeable CIFilter over video

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

I am currently trying to implement something similar to Instagram's story feature where you take a picture or a video and when swiping left or right you change the current filter over the content. ( here is an example of what I managed to do in my app for images https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsIyL.jpg )

As you can see in the example, I got it done for images but now my problem is that I am trying to make if work for videos aswell and I am a bit lost from where to start.

```
final class Filter: NSObject {
    var isEnabled: Bool = true
    var overlayImage: CIImage?
    var ciFilter: CIFilter?

    init(ciFilter: CIFilter?) {
        self.ciFilter = ciFilter

        super.init()
    }

    /// Empty filter for the original photo
    static func emptyFilter() -> Filter {
        return Filter(ciFilter: nil)
    }
    
    func imageByProcessingImage(_ image: CIImage, at time: CFTimeInterval) -> CIImage? {
        guard isEnabled else { return image }
        var image = image

        if let overlayImage = overlayImage {
            image = overlayImage.composited(over: image)
        }

        guard let ciFilter = ciFilter else {
            return image
        }

        ciFilter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        return ciFilter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage
    }
}



class StoriesImageView: UIView {
    private var metalView: MTKView?
    
    private var ciImage: CIImage?
    private var preferredCIImageTransform: CGAffineTransform?
    
    private let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    private var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue?
    private var context: CIContext?
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        metalView?.frame = bounds
    }
    
    override func setNeedsDisplay() {
        super.setNeedsDisplay()
        
        metalView?.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    func setImage(with image: UIImage) {
        preferredCIImageTransform = preferredCIImageTransform(from: image)
        
        if let cgImage = image.cgImage {
            ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            loadContextIfNeeded()
        }
        
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    /// Return the image fitted to 1080x1920.
    func renderedUIImage() -> UIImage? {
        return renderedUIImage(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1920)))
    }
    
    /// Returns CIImage in fitted to main screen bounds.
    func renderedCIIImage() -> CIImage? {
        return renderedCIImage(in: CGRect(rect: bounds, contentScale: UIScreen.main.scale))
    }
    
    func renderedUIImage(in rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        if let image = renderedCIImage(in: rect), let context = context {
            if let imageRef = context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    func renderedCIImage(in rect: CGRect) -> CIImage? {
        if var image = ciImage, let transform = preferredCIImageTransform {
            image = image.transformed(by: transform)
            
            return scaleAndResize(image, for: rect)
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    private func cleanupContext() {
        metalView?.removeFromSuperview()
        metalView?.releaseDrawables()
        metalView = nil
    }
    
    private func loadContextIfNeeded() {
        setContext()
    }
    
    private func setContext() {
        let mView = MTKView(frame: bounds, device: device)
        mView.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
        mView.framebufferOnly = false
        mView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
        mView.contentScaleFactor = contentScaleFactor
        mView.delegate = self
        
        metalView = mView
        commandQueue = device?.makeCommandQueue()
        context = CIContext(mtlDevice: device!)
        
        insertSubview(metalView!, at: 0)
    }
    
    private func scaleAndResize(_ image: CIImage, for rect: CGRect) -> CIImage {
        let imageSize = image.extent.size
        
        let horizontalScale = rect.size.width / imageSize.width
        let verticalScale = rect.size.height / imageSize.height
        
        let scale = min(horizontalScale, verticalScale)
        return image.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
    }
    
    private func preferredCIImageTransform(from image: UIImage) -> CGAffineTransform {
        if image.imageOrientation == .up {
            return .identity
        }
        
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
        
        switch image.imageOrientation {
            case .down, .downMirrored:
                transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: image.size.height)
                transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi)
            case .left, .leftMirrored:
                transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: 0)
                transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
            case .right, .rightMirrored:
                transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
                transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi / -2)
            case .up, .upMirrored: break
            @unknown default: fatalError("Unknown image orientation")
        }
        
        switch image.imageOrientation {
            case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
                transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: 0)
                transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
            case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
                transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.height, y: 0)
                transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
            case .up, .down, .left, .right: break
            @unknown default: fatalError("Unknown image orientation")
        }
        
        return transform
    }
}

extension StoriesImageView: MTKViewDelegate {
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        autoreleasepool {
            let rect = CGRect(rect: view.bounds, contentScale: UIScreen.main.scale)
            
            if let image = renderedCIImage(in: rect) {
                
                let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
                guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable else {
                    return
                }
                
                let heightDifference = (view.drawableSize.height - image.extent.size.height) / 2
                let destination = CIRenderDestination(width: Int(view.drawableSize.width),
                                                      height: Int(view.drawableSize.height - heightDifference),
                                                      pixelFormat: view.colorPixelFormat,
                                                      commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                                                      mtlTextureProvider: { () -> MTLTexture in
                    return drawable.texture
                })
                
                _ = try? context?.startTask(toRender: image, to: destination)
                
                commandBuffer?.present(drawable)
                commandBuffer?.commit()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {}
}


final class StoriesSwipeableImageView: StoriesImageView {
    private let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    private let preprocessingFilter: Filter? = nil
    
    var isRefreshingAutomaticallyWhenScrolling: Bool = true
    
    var filters: [Filter]? {
        didSet {
            updateScrollViewContentSize()
            updateCurrentSelected(notify: true)
        }
    }

    var selectedFilter: Filter? {
        didSet {
            if selectedFilter != oldValue {
                setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        setup()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        scrollView.frame = bounds
        updateScrollViewContentSize()
    }

    private func setup() {
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.bounces = true
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear

        addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    private func updateScrollViewContentSize() {
        let filterCount = filters?.count ?? 0
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: filterCount * Int(frame.size.width) * 3,
                                        height: Int(frame.size.height))

        if let selectedFilter = selectedFilter {
            scroll(to: selectedFilter, animated: false)
        }
    }

    private func scroll(to filter: Filter, animated: Bool) {
        if let index = filters?.firstIndex(where: { $0 === filter }) {
            let contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentSize.width / 3 + scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index), y: 0)
            scrollView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: animated)
            updateCurrentSelected(notify: false)
        } else {
            fatalError("Filter is not available in filters collection")
        }
    }

    private func updateCurrentSelected(notify: Bool) {
        guard frame.size.width != 0 else { return }

        let filterCount = filters?.count ?? 0
        let selectedIndex = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width / 2) / Int(scrollView.frame.size.width) % filterCount
        var newFilterGroup: Filter?

        if selectedIndex >= 0 && selectedIndex < filterCount {
            newFilterGroup = filters?[selectedIndex]
        } else {
            fatalError("Invalid contentOffset")
        }

        if selectedFilter != newFilterGroup {
            selectedFilter = newFilterGroup

            if notify {
                // Notify delegate?
            }
        }
    }

    override func renderedCIImage(in rect: CGRect) -> CIImage? {
        guard var image = super.renderedCIImage(in: rect) else {
            print("Failed to render image")
            return nil
        }

        let timeinterval: CFTimeInterval = 0

        if let preprocessingFilter = self.preprocessingFilter {
            image = preprocessingFilter.imageByProcessingImage(image, at: timeinterval)!
        }

        let extent = image.extent
        let contentSize = scrollView.bounds.size

        if contentSize.width == 0 {
            return image
        }

        let filtersCount = filters?.count ?? 0

        if filtersCount == 0 {
            return image
        }

        let ratio = scrollView.contentOffset.x / contentSize.width

        var index = Int(ratio)
        let upIndex = Int(ceil(ratio))
        let remaningRatio = ratio - CGFloat(index)
        var xImage = extent.size.width * -remaningRatio

        var outputImage: CIImage? = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0))

        while index <= upIndex {
            let currentIndex = index % filtersCount
            let filter = filters?[currentIndex]
            var filteredImage = filter?.imageByProcessingImage(image, at: timeinterval)
            filteredImage = filteredImage?.cropped(to:
                CGRect(x: extent.origin.x + xImage,
                       y: extent.origin.y,
                       width: extent.size.width,
                       height: extent.size.height)
            )
            guard let output = outputImage else { return nil }
            outputImage = filteredImage?.composited(over: output)
            xImage += extent.size.width
            index += 1
        }

        outputImage = outputImage?.cropped(to: extent)

        return outputImage
    }
}

extension StoriesSwipeableImageView: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let width = scrollView.frame.size.width
        let contentOffsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let contentSizeWidth = scrollView.contentSize.width
        let normalWidth = CGFloat(filters?.count ?? 0) * width

        if width > 0 && contentSizeWidth > 0 {
            if contentOffsetX <= 0 {
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: contentOffsetX + normalWidth, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
            } else if contentOffsetX + width >= contentSizeWidth {
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: contentOffsetX - normalWidth, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
            }
        }

        if isRefreshingAutomaticallyWhenScrolling {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateCurrentSelected(notify: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateCurrentSelected(notify: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateCurrentSelected(notify: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        if !decelerate {
            updateCurrentSelected(notify: true)
        }
    }

}
```

These 3 are the classes that do the magic for the image part. Does anyone have a suggestion or a starting point for this? I tried looking over at https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder but I get a bit lost in Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9 / OS X 10.11 / tvOS, there's a convenience method for applying CIFilters to video. It works on an AVVideoComposition, so you can use it both for playback and for file-to-file import/export. See AVVideoComposition.init(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:) for the method docs.

There's an example in Apple's Core Image Programming Guide, too:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in

    // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges
    let source = request.sourceImage.clampingToExtent()
    filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    // Vary filter parameters based on video timing
    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
    filter.setValue(seconds * 10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    // Crop the blurred output to the bounds of the original image
    let output = filter.outputImage!.cropping(to: request.sourceImage.extent)

    // Provide the filter output to the composition
    request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
})
```

That part sets up the composition. After you've done that, you can either play it by assigning it to an AVPlayer or write it to a file with AVAssetExportSession. Since you're after the latter, here's an example of that:

```
let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1200)
export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
export.outputURL = outURL
export.videoComposition = composition

export.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler(/*...*/)
```

There's a bit more about this in [the WWDC15 session on Core Image, starting around 20 minutes in](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-510/?time=1222).

Comment: Unofrtunately that donsen't really answer what I need. I got the the part with applying filters, right now I am trying to apply them with an animated overlay scroll.